# Azure Search Autocomplete with Escape Special Characters

Tags: azure, special-characters, msdn, azure-cognitive-search, analyzer

I am having issues with including special characters such as -, @, # and others in the response of autocomplete.

I am using .Net Core with C#, and Microsoft.Azure.Search package.

I am new to Azure Search, so please be generous to provide me with detailed explanation with some guidance.

So far, I have created an index with the field a suggester as below.

```
private async Task StartIndexAsync(bool resetIndexer = true)
{
    await CreateIndexAsync(new[]{
            new Field(nameof(ProjectSearchModel.Id),                      DataType.String)     { IsKey = true,  IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = false, IsSortable = false, IsFacetable = false, IsRetrievable = true},
            new Field(nameof(ProjectSearchModel.Name),                    DataType.String)     { IsKey = false,  IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = false, IsSortable = false, IsFacetable = false, IsRetrievable = true},
            new Field(nameof(ProjectSearchModel.Number),                  DataType.String)     { IsKey = false,  IsSearchable = false, IsFilterable = false, IsSortable = false, IsFacetable = false, IsRetrievable = true}
            },
        new[] {
            nameof(ProjectSearchModel.Name),
            nameof(ProjectSearchModel.Number),
        });

    await CreateDatasourceAsync();
    await StartIndexerAsync(resetIndexer);
}
```

```
internal async Task CreateIndexAsync(string indexName, IList<Field> mapFields, IList<string> sugFields)
{
    // Create the Azure Search index based on the included schema
    try
    {
        var definition = new Index()
        {
            Name = indexName,
            Fields = mapFields,
            Suggesters = new List<Suggester>() {new Suggester()
            {
                Name = "sg",
                SourceFields = sugFields,
            }}
        };

        await _searchClient.Indexes.CreateOrUpdateAsync(definition);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error creating index: {0}\r\n", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

With this index setup, I am calling autocomplete with the function below.

```
public override async Task<AutocompleteResult> AutocompleteAsync(int take, string text)
{
    // Setup the suggest parameters.
    var parameters = new AutocompleteParameters()
    {
        SearchFields = new [] { "Name", "Number"},
        AutocompleteMode = AutocompleteMode.TwoTerms,
        UseFuzzyMatching = true,
        Top = take
    };
    var completeResult = await base.AutocompleteAsync(parameters, text);
    return completeResult;
}
```

My expected result would be pyh2982@gmail.com for Name field when I pass pyh in text. However, the actual result is just pyh2982 gmail.com, with missing @ inbetween.

I have researched a bit about Analyzer, but I am confused as to what analyzer I should be choosing.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzer is a piece of code responsible to tokenise and index your content. The standard analyzer transforms the text to lowercase, and break on every stop word. As far as I know, it should index your email as one single piece. You can do a test and perform an autocomplete without '@' symbol and '-'. For example: pyh2982 gmail com and check if it works for you.

PS: If you are using Lucene mode (queryType=full), then you should escape special chars. Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax

Comment: Okay, the problem with this is that if I want to use autocomplete, then I need to add that specific field to the suggester. Azure Search doesn't let me change an analyzer other than the default one for any fields that are included in the suggester. When I try to do so, I get an error message saying "The request is invalid. Details: definition : Field 'UpdatedBy/Email' in suggester 'sg' uses an unsupported analyzers configuration. Suggesters are only supported with the default analyzer and language analyzers in this version of the API". The standard analyzer breaks special characters like @.

Comment: the "work around" is to replace the '@' to '||' for example, then you perform the same before send the text to autocomplete. I can't think about another way